# boost date time -- output format

Tags: c++, boost

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  boost::local_time::local_time_facet* facet = new boost::local_time::local_time_facet("%e %b %Y %T %q");
  std::ostringstream date_osstr;
  date_osstr.imbue(std::locale(date_osstr.getloc(), facet));
  const boost::posix_time::ptime& now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
  date_osstr << now;

  std::cout << date_osstr.str() << '\n';
}
```

I expected that the output should have the following format:

> 1 Jul 2003 10:52:37 +0200

But the output have the following format:

> 2014-Apr-28 12:40:04

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually use a `local_date_time` to benefit from the `local_time_facet`:

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>

using namespace boost;
static local_time::time_zone_ptr const utc_time_zone(new local_time::posix_time_zone("GMT"));

int main()
{
    local_time::local_time_facet* facet = new local_time::local_time_facet("%e %b %Y %T %q");

    posix_time::ptime my_ptime = posix_time::second_clock::universal_time();
    local_time::local_date_time now(my_ptime, utc_time_zone);

    std::ostringstream date_osstr;
    date_osstr.imbue(std::locale(date_osstr.getloc(), facet));
    date_osstr << now;

    std::cout << date_osstr.str() << '\n';
}
```

Prints

```
28 Apr 2014 12:59:01 +0000
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b02973941a151850)**

Answer (score 2):

The facet you're using is for local_time objects but you're printing a posix_time.  Instead, use this:

```
boost::posix_time::time_facet* facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet("%e %b %Y %T %q");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but now I don't have %q part in the output

Comment: Ah, I see that %q is for local times only, in which case you probably need @sehe's solution instead.  Two sides of the same coin, sort of.